# What is the best approach to solving a system of linear equations using Python and object-oriented programming?

Tags: object, oop

write a program the solve the following equations to find the values of x, y, and z. x+1/2y-z=5 -3x+5y=10 2x+3y+4z=-4

write a program the solve the following equations to find the values of x, y, and z.        x+1/2y-z=5                 -3x+5y=10                 2x+3y+4z=-4

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.